# How do I go to/highlight a specific cell ID in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

Say I am on A1, and I want to instantly go to/highlight/focus Z99. How would I go to that cell ID (or row/column) with a keyboard shortcut or within the menu or context menu?

There is [Ctrl+G for Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/440449/go-to-specific-row-number-in-excel) but that only opens a find box in Google Sheets. It doesn't seem like this feature exists as I have searched for a bit now, but hopefully it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Sheets doesn't have a similar shortcut.

You could create a macro / script, a URL query, or use an add-on that add this feature.

**URL query**

Maybe the easiest is to use a URL query, on the browser address bar just add `&range=Z99` to the spreadsheet URL and press enter.

**Macro / Script**

Please read [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) and [Google Sheets Macros](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros)

Here is a simple script. Adopters could add the validations that works best for them.

If we add it as a macro we could assign a keyboard shortcut to call it in the form <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Number</kbd>  (Tools > Macros > Import then Tools > Macros > Manage Macros).

```
function GoTo() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var Ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var buttons = Ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL;
  var response = Ui.prompt('Go to', 'Where do you want to go?', buttons);
  if(response.getSelectedButton() === Ui.Button.OK){
    var address = response.getResponseText();
    spreadsheet.getRange(address).activateAsCurrentCell();
  } 
};
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/rubenrivera/591197229149022eb2e4ddc89be91094)

Reference

- [Keyboard shortcuts for Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks, the URL query is doable for now. I am still quite surprised that they don't have this feature. Can I really be one of the few who would use this feature? Now I am wondering if a macro do a pop up? And can a macro do a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Macros do pop ups, but you should edit the macro to add the pop up, and the do a keyboard shortcut

Comment: @ElijahLynn I added the code of a macro.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful until their is native goto! I got it working and now ctrl + alt + shift + 1 brings up the popup, enter the cell, then tab, enter and done.